# Are class variables in the scope of instance methods or class methods?

Tags: python, class, methods, scope

- Do the class variables come in the scope of the methods defined for a Python class?
- How shall I access a class variable in a method (class method or instance method or static method) and possibly change it?
- What's the best way? For example I might want to keep count of how many instances of the class have been created.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071491/1809377) that class variables are in scope of the method parameter list. To use the class variable there, I should refer it just as `counter` and not as `MyClass.counter` because the class is in the middle of being defined, however I can access it as `MyClass.counter` in the `__init__` method. Does it mean the class is fully defined when inside the `__init__` method?

**edit:** I also want to know why is `counter` in scope in parameter list of a method but not in the method body?

```
class MyClass(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self): # counter is in scope here. can be used as default argument
        counter += 1  # Counter not in scope. Throws UnboundLocalError

    def printCount(self):
        print counter  # Counter not in scope. Throws UnboundLocalError
```

Comment: I asked here to get an explanation why is it so.

Comment: You should get `UnboundLocalError` error not global error for this.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: So if you read that answer you linked to, you'll notice that the answerer never referenced `counter` inside the method body... so no, it's not in scope unless you mention it by class name.

Comment: When the class body has finished executing the variable `counter` has been converted to `Myclass.counter`, so to access that variable inside methods you need to use either the class name or `self`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within methods, you can access class attributes in two different ways:

1. By referencing the class, then the attribute:

   ```
   MyClass.counter
   ```
2. By accessing the attribute on the instance, `self`:

   ```
   self.counter
   ```

   This only works if there is no *instance attribute* masking `counter`.

The problem is that when you **set** an attribute on the instance, the class attribute no longer can be accessed on `self`:

```
self.counter += 1
```

would set an instance attribute the first time you run this, and the class attribute would no longer be accessed.

If you want to *set* a class attribute, you'll have to use the first method of addressing it then:

```
class MyClass(object):
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self): 
        MyClass.counter += 1

    def printCount(self):
        # these both work:
        print self.counter
        print MyClass.counter
```

You cannot refer to `counter` as a local in the methods. Outside of the class definition body they are *not* local or global names. Only inside the [`class` body](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) can you do that:

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame *[...]*, using a newly created local namespace and the original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains only function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. [...] A class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.

In other words, when Python executes the `class` body, `counter` and `__init__` and `printCount` are local names, and during the execution you can refer to those names as locals. Thus, you can use `counter` to define a default value for a method argument, or base calculations on it. But once the class is constructed, that namespace is gone, and you'll have  to refer to `MyClass.<name>` instead.

Comment: could you please explain a bit regarding my question in edit which is what I actually wanted to ask. Thanks :)

Comment: @ajay: when defining a class, everything inside the `class` statement is executed like a function. `counter` is a local variable in that 'function', as are the function *definitions*. The local namespace of that function becomes the class body. So `counter` is a local, `__init__` is another, etc.

Comment: @ajay: So you can refer to `counter` as a local name at that time. But when the class has completed being defined, those local names are  gone, they are now part of the class. You'll have to refer to `MyClass.<name>` instead.

Comment: Please add these in the answer. It will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another simple explanation:**

**1. Do the class variables come in the scope of the methods defined for a Python class?**

**Here is class variable explanation:**

- A variable that is shared by all instances of a class.
- It is defined within a class but outside any of the class's methods.
- A Class variable can be access by using the class name dot the variable name.

NB: Class variable are store in `class_name.__dict__`  i.e shared to all instances.

NB: Instance variable are store in `instance.__dict__` i.e only to the current instance.

NB: it is always a good idea to access class variable with class name to reduce the confusion and not to over-write with the instance variable.

**Here is the snippet:**

```
class ClassA(object):
    _counter = 0
    def __init__(self, val):
       self._counter = val

    def show_me(self):
        print 'Class variable: %d' % ClassA._counter
        print 'Instance variable: %d' % self._counter

obj = ClassA(1000)

obj.show_me()
print ClassA.__dict__['_counter']
print obj.__dict__['_counter']
```

Output:

```
Class variable: 0
Instance variable: 1000
0
1000
```

**2. How shall I access a class variable in a method (class method or instance method or static method) and possibly change it?**

You can access class variable using class_name dot variable name ie

```
ClassA._counter
```

**3. What's the best way? For example I might want to keep count of how many instances of the class have been created.**

As far I know its better to over-write `__new__` method because `__new__` is calling for every object creating and update your class variable `_counter` like as below snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class ClassA(object):
    # this _counter is in the class.__dict__ which shared across all instance
    _counter = 0
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        ob = super(ClassA, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        ClassA._counter += 1
        return ob

    def __init__(self, val):
        # this _counter is in the instance dictionary which is not shared
        self._counter = val*val

    def total_instance(self):
        return ClassA._counter

# Lets create three instance
for i in range(1,4):
    obj = ClassA(i)
    print 'class variable _counter : %d' % obj.total_instance()
    print 'instance variable _counter : %d' % obj._counter
```

Output:

```
class variable _counter : 1
instance variable _counter : 1
class variable _counter : 2
instance variable _counter : 4
class variable _counter : 3
instance variable _counter : 9
```

NB: in the above example I am trying to show you the difference of instance variable `_counter` and class variable `_counter`.

Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: class variable can also be accessed in the parameter list without prefixing it with the class name. Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: ok if you access the class variable from the parameter list, then are you able to increment it ? to count the number of instances. You can but you need to write more code.